# Why do people not use Multiple ports to communicate between 2 computers for the same protocol?

Tags: networking, port

There is at least one protocol I am aware of that uses multiple ports for its working (FTP, port 20 and 21 for data and control respectively) What I'd like to know is why no other protocol does this, is there some negative impact to the protocol if that is the case (yes, we will have to make separate sockets for each port used, but other than that is there any hurdle)

Also, if we can effectively use multiple ports for transmitting data between 2 devices; can spreading that data over different ports, instead of sending it all via one port make it harder for anyone to intercept the data?

Comment: Because there is usually no point. FTP is a special case because you need to be able to interrupt a transfer. Security is a solved problem, via SSL. Ports are a scarce resource and not to be squandered.

Comment: well, i guess that sums it up!
However, hypothetically speaking, if someone were to develop such a wasteful method, would it be of any use at all?

Comment: I meant in whether it is even remotely tougher for an interceptor to read the messages sent.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking such a question is meaningless. It would be useful if it was useful, which is only decidable in a specific case. If you want security use SSL. Wasting resources to get partial security is pointless.